# Wordpress добавить уникальный класс к каждому посту

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо добавить каждой записи уникальный класс, содержащий порядковый номер поста, что бы получилось как то так

```
<article class="article-1">
...
</article>
<article class="article-2">
...
</article>
```

и так до class="article-30" а после добавлять классы опять начиная с class="article-1".

Вот мой код:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: С чем у вас возникли затруднения? Добавте это в вопрос вместе с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

У вас цикл по постам в одном файле, а вывод тега `<article>` - в другом. Надо создать глобальную переменную-счётчик постов и использовать остаток от деления этого счётчика на 30.

```
global $my_post_count;
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    $my_post_count = 0;
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );
    $my_post_count++;
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

В файле loop-templates/content.php

```
global $my_post_count;
//...
<article class="article-<?php echo ($my_post_count % 30) + 1; ?>">
```